# iphone 6 Screen bounds give me iphone 5 frame

Tags: ios, ios8

I am tring to get the iphone 6 screen bounds but it give me the iphone 5 frame

```
 NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds))
 {{0, 0}, {568, 320}}
```

Comment: +1 for the keywords in this question that got me from Google to the other SO post.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to use `[UIScreen mainScreen].nativeBounds` introduced in ios8.

Comment: Nope, that’s for things like games that can benefit from rendering at the screen’s native resolution rather than the higher-resolution-then-downscaled thing the iPhone 6 Plus does.